# Symfony2 - Form Event Listener

Tags: php, forms, symfony

Could someone explain me, how to use event listener? I read some documentation, but I can't understand...

Could someone show me example?

**For example:**

I have 2 types of mobiles:

1) Apple
2) Nokia

```
$form->add('mobile', 'choice', [
                'choices' => [
                    'apple' => 'Apple',
                    'nokia' => 'Nokia'
                ]
            ]);
```

and each mobile have 2 models.

Apple = iPhone 4, iPhone 5

```
$form->add('model', 'choice', [
                'choices' => [
                    'iphone 4' => 'iPhone 4',
                    'iphone 5' => 'iPhone 5'
                ]
            ]);
```

Nokia = Lumia 920, Lumia 925

```
$form->add('model', 'choice', [
                'choices' => [
                    'lumia 920' => 'Lumia 920',
                    'Lumia 925' => 'Lumia 925'
                ]
            ]);
```

Form have to display right choice after I select "mobile".

Thanks so much

Comment: http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/